# Display string of SVG on canvas

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, svg

I want to display a string of SVG on a canvas;

One method is to have a dummy `img` element on the page and use it to "transform" the SVG into something you can draw on a canvas.

```js
const svg='<svg id=\"Layer_1\" data-name=\"Layer 1\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"1657\" height=\"1235\" viewBox=\"0 0 1657 1235\">\r\n  <title>MTF</title>\r\n<rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" stroke="blue" fill="purple" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-opacity="0.8"/></svg>';
const svgURL = `data:image/svg+xml,${svg}`;

const img = document.getElementById('i');
img.setAttribute('src', svgURL);
const canvas = document.getElementById('c');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="c">
  </canvas>
</div>
<img src="" id="i"/>
```

But this seems inefficient.  How can I write the svg variable onto a canvas directly?

Alternatively, I could simply write it inside e.g. a div tag as it is valid code.  However, I am using canvas to convert the SVG to png/jpg and save it to disk.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg). It allows you to render SVG documents directly onto a canvas.